# how to get a subdocument data mongoose in frontend with ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

i want to get all informations about collection commercant which include another collection personne in the Front with ReactJs.
with postman, they return all data but in the front they not understand the personne's data
My schema looks like this

```
const commercantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typeCom:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }, 
    numRegistre:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    personne:[{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref:"Personne"
    }]
    
})
```

```
const personneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nom:{
        type:String,
        required:true}, 
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true}, 
    type:{
        type:String,
        required:true},
    nomResponsable:{
        type:String,
        required:true},
    etat:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false }
},{timestamps:true})
```

API :

```
router.get('/allcom',(req,res)=>{
    Commercant.find()
.populate({
    path: 'personne',
    math: {_id:'peronne'},
})   
    .then(commercants=>{
        res.json({commercants})
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })

})
```

in the front

```
const [data,setData] = useState([])
useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('/allcom',{
            headers:{
                "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            }
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
         console.log(result)
            setData(result.commercants)
        })
    },[])
....
```

[console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkVvz.jpg)

[react component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuWLl.jpg)

Comment: any attempt you did on the frontend?

Comment: `useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('/allcom',{
            headers:{
                "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            }
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
         //   console.log(result)
            setData(result.commercants)
        })
    },[])`

Comment: can you share what you got at console.log(result)  ? and also if you can add the code to your question and not here in the comment section please

Comment: i add it.. you can check it again

Comment: then you want to access all the personne data?

Comment: yes.. i tested the API with postman it's work as i want.. but in the front it does not return them

Comment: it looks like it returns 4 data of personne based on your console log tho, in an array

Comment: no, it's 4 commercant and each commercant has an id personne also with 2 another data (numRegistre and typeCom)

Comment: my problem is in the front.. it's not get them

Comment: you can access each personne of the commercants by the index like `result.commercants[0].personne` `result.commercants[1].personne` and so on ..

Comment: but i have dynamical access.. it doesn't work

Comment: how do you want to access it?

Comment: by using (data.map(item=>{...}))

Comment: you can do result.commercants.map(obj=>{return obj.personne})

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
result.commercants.map(arrItem => {return arrItem.personne})
```

Comment: can you console log `console.log(result.commercants.map(arrItem => {return arrItem.personne}))`

Comment: isn't that what you need?

Comment: it still does not work in the frontend (in render) ..

Comment: I shared it above.. 'nom' belongs to personne collection and numRegistre to commercant collection.. i can't get 'nom' in the frontend.. but it is displayed in console log